# Get index of multiple selected items in listview JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

Can anybody help me to get the index of items selected in a list view.
I was trying in JAVA FX but all my work went in vain.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `selectionModel` to get a list of those indices:

```
ListView listView = ...
```

```
ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
```

Answer (score -1):

this will capture the selected line into a variable for you to use at will:

`int selectedIndex = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();`